# Adjust date format after using dput in R

Tags: r

As you can see, it misconfigured the date in my `database`. How can I fix this or is it that way??

```
library(readxl)
df<-read_excel('C:/Desktop/example.xlsx')

dput(df)

> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1629936000, 1629936000, 1629936000, 
1629936000, 1629936000, 1629936000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Upd = structure(c(1577836800, 1577836800, 
1577836800, 1577836800, 1580601600, 1580601600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Value 1` = c(12, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: It hasn't really 'misconfigured' your date. Excel stored it as a numeric representation of a date with a particular way of displaying it, R stored it as a numeric representation of a date with a different way of displaying it. You can hardcode the format in R to match Excel, but then it won't actually be a date any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reformat the data:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Date, Upd), ~format(.x, "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       Upd        `Value 1`
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>
1 26/08/2021 01/01/2020        12
2 26/08/2021 01/01/2020        12
3 26/08/2021 01/01/2020         3
4 26/08/2021 01/01/2020         4
5 26/08/2021 02/02/2020         5
6 26/08/2021 02/02/2020         6
```

Or with base R

```r
df$Date <- format(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
df$Upd  <- format(df$Upd, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`

```
df[c("Date", "Upd")] <- lapply(df[c("Date", "Upd")], format, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

-output

```
 df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       Upd        `Value 1`
  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>
1 26/08/2021 01/01/2020        12
2 26/08/2021 01/01/2020        12
3 26/08/2021 01/01/2020         3
4 26/08/2021 01/01/2020         4
5 26/08/2021 02/02/2020         5
6 26/08/2021 02/02/2020         6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're going after, but I deal a lot with excel files where a column that should be a date get's imported as numeric.  I made this little function to help me out with that:

```
excel_date_number_to_date <- function(number) {

  as.Date(number, origin = "1899-12-30")
}
```

For your dataframe you can use it like this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Date, Upd), ~excel_date_number_to_date(.x)))
```